# How to Process Multiple Input Form Field in Django

Tags: python, html

I would like to *register/process* a list of 1 to 5 users information in Python using Django as an user interface.  This is not a typical user registration process.  I simply wanted to process the user data.  User information contains 3 fields, First Name, Last Name, and Gender.  I am able to obtain one user information but unsure on how to gather the second, third, fourth, or the fifth user.

The input box that contain the user information are added dynamically using jQuery.  It can have 1 entry or 5 entries depending on whether the user add more field.  I tried to make addName.html and views.py to process the list but it's incorrect.  My ultimate goal is to use these data and pass it to my Python program as illustrated in my views.py

```
# Perform a Python Script using data gathered
# registerName = addName ('first_name', 'last_name', 'gender')
```

I appreciate the help and apologize for the long post.  I wanted to make it clear and easy to understand.

*By the way, don't mind the Male Radio Button with the Female Name.  It's for example purposes.*

**models.py**

```
# MySite/formtest/models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Form (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField (max_length = 20, null = False, blank = False)
    last_name = models.CharField (max_length = 20, null = False, blank = False)
    gender = models.CharField (max_length = 12, null = False, blank = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

**addName.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female

        <p><label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName1" placeholder="John" required="True" maxlength="20">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
        <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName1" placeholder="Doe" required="True" maxlength="20">
        <input type="button" value="add"></p>

        <p><label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName2" placeholder="John" required="True" maxlength="20">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
        <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName2" placeholder="Doe" required="True" maxlength="20">
        <a href="#">remove</a></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Process Name"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from formtest.models import Form

# Create your views here.
def addNameDisplay (request):
    c = {}
    c.update (csrf (request))
    return render (request, 'formtest/addName.html')

def Process (request):
    i = 1

    while (i <= 5):
        Form (first_name = request.POST ['firstName[i]'],
              last_name = request.POST ['lastName[i]'],
              gender = request.POST ['gender']).save ()

        # Perform a Python Script using data gathered
        # registerName = addName ('first_name', 'last_name', 'gender')
        i += 1

    return HttpResponseRedirect ('results')

def Results (request):
    nameInfo = Form.objects.all ()
    context = {'nameInfo': nameInfo}
    return render (request, 'formtest/results.html', context)
```

**results.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for name in nameInfo %}
    <li><b>First Name</b>: {{ name.first_name }} <b>Last Name</b>: {{ name.last_name }} <b>Gender</b>: {{ name.gender }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

    <a href="addname">Add More Names</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per HTML standard rules, an ID attribute must be unique, thus you cannot have multiple id=firstName, meaning your IDs should increment INSTEAD of your name ATTRs. Your name attrs should be the same, e.g. all firstname fields NAME should be firstName.

This will create a POST array named firstName with each of your IDs as children. This name/id behavior/relationship is normal for checkbox/radio buttons, but also applies to most/any form element.

Instead of using a while loop, you could loop through each name(ed) attr in the POST. e.g.

```
for firstname in request.POST['firstName']:
```

Further, in your view, you could check to make sure form.is_valid() which can be reviewed in the Django [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) documentation.

For example:

```
def my_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            for blah in blah:
                #this is where you would obtain FN, LN and GN for EACH "user" and put it into kwargs
                kwargs = {}
                form.save(**kwargs)
        except:
            #you are responsible for determining what to do on failure
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Comment: I've made a few changes to my HTML portion but then I ran into some issue with the "form.is_valid ()".  Since my model is not an attribute of a Django Form, your solution doesn't work.  I had to change my models and my views.

Comment: Well, hopefully my input helps you find your way regardless the path :)  Happy coding.

Comment: It does and I appreciate it. I'm new at Python let alone added Django to the mix.  Quite overwhelming so I may not know what I'm doing.

Comment: I recommend always starting with the simplest form of an idea. Once you solve a single instance, you'll have a better understanding of how to solve multiple instances.

Comment: I agree.  I was able to get the information that I needed with just one instance.  The next step for me is how to get the data in multiple instances.